# Angular JS error with factories

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to understand how factories work and have hit a road block. I'm following along with [this guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffastandfluid.com%2Fpublicdownloads%2FAngularJSIn60MinutesIsh_DanWahlin_May2013.pdf&ei=_QeGU568J4KYqAbnhYKYDA&usg=AFQjCNH4SxCtq4GeuylVMZuithk_eA7Dcg&sig2=mk8btYQxakwBGR93VDT5Mw&bvm=bv.67720277,d.b2k) on page 88 or so.

Running my code results in these console errors.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined

```
<div ng-app="timeEntry">
    <div ng-controller="timeEntryController">
        <p class="lead">Factory Test</p>
        <p>**** {{testing}}</p>
        <p>******** {{testing2}}</p>
    </div>
</div>


var timeEntry = angular.module('timeEntry', []);

timeEntry.controller('timeEntryController', ['$scope', function ($scope, loadData) {
    $scope.testing = 'test';
    $scope.testing2 = loadData.getData();
}]);

timeEntry.factory('loadData', function ($http) {
    var test = 'test data';
    var factory = {};
    factory.getData = function () {
        return test;
    };
    return factory;
});
```

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dgdavidson/QPc3j/2/

I'm sure that the error will be frightfully obvious, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the string 'loadData' to your declaration:

So change this:

```
timeEntry.controller('timeEntryController', ['$scope', function ($scope, loadData) {
```

to:

```
timeEntry.controller('timeEntryController', ['$scope', 'loadData', function ($scope, loadData) {
```

([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgdavidson/QPc3j/2/))

The error you're seeing is because Angular is passing `undefined` into `loadData`.  And, of course, `undefined` has no property `getData`.

This is such an easy/common mistake that some people skip manually declaring the strings and use [ngMin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) to do it for them (for instance adding it to your grunt file).  This allows you to then use the following style of declaration where you don't have to ensure strings match parameters:

```
timeEntry.controller('timeEntryController', function ($scope, loadData) {
```